# linux c flush serial buffer after writing

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port, embedded-linux

Simple problem. When I write to `/dev/ttyS1`, it does not flush it immediately. This is probably something to do with my initialization of serial port... But I can not figure it out! My code is like this:

```
#define BAUDRATE B115200
#define MODEMDEVICE "/dev/ttyS1"
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1 /* POSIX compliant source */
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

volatile int STOP = FALSE;

void signal_handler_IO(int status); /* definition of signal handler */
int wait_flag = TRUE; /* TRUE while no signal received */


int main()
{
    int fd, c, res;
    struct termios oldtio, newtio;
    struct sigaction saio; /* definition of signal action */
    char buf[255];

    /* open the device to be non-blocking (read will return immediatly) */
    fd = open(MODEMDEVICE, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror(MODEMDEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* install the signal handler before making the device asynchronous */
    saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
    //saio.sa_mask = 0;
    saio.sa_flags = 0;
    saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
    sigaction(SIGIO, &saio, NULL);

    /* allow the process to receive SIGIO */
    fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
    /* Make the file descriptor asynchronous (the manual page says only
     O_APPEND and O_NONBLOCK, will work with F_SETFL...) */
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FASYNC);

    tcgetattr(fd, &oldtio); /* save current port settings */
    /* set new port settings for canonical input processing */
    newtio.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CRTSCTS | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR | ICRNL;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_lflag = ICANON;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newtio);

    int i = 0;

    /* loop while waiting for input. normally we would do something
     useful here */
    while (1) {
        printf(".\n");
        usleep(100000);
        //tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH);
        //tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
        i++;
        if (i == 20) {
            // ------------------ write to serial ----------------------
            int n = write(fd, "ATZ\n", 4);
            if (n < 0)
                fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);

        }

        /* after receiving SIGIO, wait_flag = FALSE, input is available
         and can be read */
        if (wait_flag == FALSE ) {
            res = read(fd, buf, 255);
            buf[res] = 0;
            printf(":%s:%d\n", buf, res);
            wait_flag = TRUE; /* wait for new input */
        }
    }
    /* restore old port settings */
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &oldtio);
}



void signal_handler_IO(int status) {
    printf("received SIGIO signal.\n");
    wait_flag = FALSE;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is happening?

Comment: Does a program like minicom or busybox' integrated microcom work as expected, without unexpected delays?  Just asking because - especially in embedded systems - interrupt problems are a rather common source of inexplicable delays in serial communications.

Comment: for input:
  when a input is recieved over the serial , the signal_handler_IO is called, which in turn sets the wait_flag to FALSE , so that the main loop reads the input from serial . this works fine.

for output:
 when i do : 
             int n = write(fd, "ATZ\n", 4);
it does not write immediately. basically the buffer is not flushed until it overflows or i call close(fd)

Comment: this is busybox programming. 

the problem is with writing , as it does not flush the buffer. reading works fine

Comment: What I mean is: exclude hardware issues first by testing your port and modem with minicom or microcom.  Only if these work as expected have a closer look at your code.

Comment: Try calling flush(fd); after each write.

Comment: hi, the hardware is fine. i have been using it for bash access . currently i disabled bash to use it for programming purpose.

Comment: i think this is happening because the serial is set in canonical mode. however , when in cannonical mode, a CRLF should flush it..but if i do : write(fd, "ATZ\r\n", 5); it does not work either!

do you mean fflush(fd) ? it did not work ..besides isnt it for stdio?

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled CTS hardware flow control by setting `CRTSCTS`.  That means that if the if the CTS input to the UART is not active, the UART should refrain from transmitting.

You might want to have a look through the *termios* man page in general.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is a solution, but adding:

```
tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH); // clear buffer
```

to clear the buffer seem to do the trick. However, there should be some more elegant and proper solution.

Comment: The documentation would suggest that TCIOFLUSH should *flush* oustanding data (drop it on the floor), rather than *send* it.

Answer (score 0):

Since "flush" can mean either clear buffer or wait until all bytes are sent, here's quotation from https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcdrain

> tcdrain() waits until all output written to the object referred to by fd has been transmitted.
>
> tcflush() discards data written to the object referred to by fd but not transmitted, or data received but not read, depending on the value of queue_selector

So,

```
tcdrain(fd); // Wait until transmission ends
tcflush(fd, TCOFLUSH); // Clear write buffer
```